# QuickCheck together with haskell-mode in emacs, ^H

Tags: haskell, emacs, quickcheck, haskell-mode

When using QuickCheck together with haskell-mode in emacs, the output starts with (continuing up to the default of 100 tests):

```
(0 tests)^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H         ^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H(1 test)
```

where ^H (Control H) is the UNIX terminal representation of backspace. Now I found [some solutions for handling ^H in emacs](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BackspaceKey), but I do not quite see how that helps me.

I've tried toggling `normal-erasure-is-backspace-mode`, but that has not worked, besides disabling my backspace key.  I wonder whether the right solution does not lie with QuickCheck or haskell-mode instead.  I've also tried fiddling with the terminal option that determines how the terminal encodes backspace and delete, but that has not made any difference.

A minimal quickCheck example:

```
import Test.QuickCheck

prop :: Int -> Bool
prop x = True

main = quickCheck prop
```

Comment: Is this the same issue as described in https://github.com/haskell/haskell-mode/issues/51 ?

Comment: Yes, it seems to be. Thanks for the link.